# Custom shape not drawing correctly on click

Tags: c#, wpf

The shape is not drawing correctly or not at all - that is, if I click towards the top left of the canvas, it will draw an ellipse but not anywhere else [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YRDr.png). Is the code logically correct? Everything seems good but perhaps I am missing something.

```
    /* in mainwindow.xaml */
    private void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnNode.IsChecked == true)
        {
            CreateNode(e.GetPosition(Canvas));
        }

    }

    private void CreateNode(Point origin)
    {
        Node n = new Node("new_" + cmbStart.Items.Count, origin) { Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Tomato), Width = 60, Height = 60 };
        Canvas.Children.Add(n);

        Canvas.SetLeft(n, origin.X - n.Width/2);
        Canvas.SetTop(n, origin.Y - n.Height/2);
    }

     /* in Node class */

     private void Init(Point p)
     {
        X = p.X;
        Y = p.Y;            
     }

     public double Y
     {
        get { return (double)this.GetValue(YProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(YProperty, value); }
     }

     public double X
     {
        get { return (double) this.GetValue(XProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(XProperty, value); }
     }

     public static readonly DependencyProperty XProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("X", typeof(double), typeof(Node), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
     public static readonly DependencyProperty YProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Y", typeof(double), typeof(Node), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

     protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
     {
        get 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("rendering at: " + this.X + ", " + this.Y + "---Scale: " + Width);
            return new EllipseGeometry(new Point(this.X, this.Y), Width, Height);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Do not set the Center point of the EllipseGeometry and Canvas.Left/Canvas.Top at the same time. Set either the one or the other.

Comment: Didn't work either. There seems to be a square rendered at the top left of the Canvas, I've uploaded an image in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

The `EllipseGeometry` constructor has the `radiusX` and `radiusY` parameters to pass radii, not diameters.

If you want to draw a full ellipse into the bounds of your custom control, you should use `Width/2` and `Height/2` as parameter values:

```
protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
{
    get 
    {
        return new EllipseGeometry(new Point(X, Y), Width / 2, Height / 2);
    }
}
```